# JQuery populate form depending on select option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add some form content depending on the option selected by a user.

For example if the user selects form 1 option the form is populated with different content that if the user selects option 2

```
<select>
<option>Form 1</option>
<option>Form 2</option>
</select>

<form>
Here we get either form 1 content or form 2 content depending on the select option selected by user.
</form>


//Form 1 content
<input type="text" value="something" />
<input type hidden="something here" />

//Form 2 content
<input type="text" value="something else here" />
<input type hidden="something else here" />
```

How can I do this using jquery?

Comment: Do u intend to use AJAX? Do u want content to come from db or something? Please be precise!!!

Comment: No I don't need ajax. The content can be hardcoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/QUbEE/1/

```
$('select').change(function () {
  if ($('option:selected', this).val() == 1) {
      //$('form').hide();
      $('#form-1').html($('<input />').attr({
        'id': 'textBox1',
            'value': 'Something is here'
    }));
  } else {
      $('#form-1').html($('<input />').attr({
        'id': 'textBox2',
            'value': 'Something ELSE is here'
      }));
  }
});
```

`Create elems depends on the change event` and then just `replace the html of the form with the new input with new values`.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your comment that the content can be hard-coded then you may write both the forms and place that forms in different divs and toggle the visibility of the div depending upon the selection made from the drop-down list

For example, say your form 1 is in div1

```
<div id="div1" class="formDiv">
  <input type="text" id="form1" value="something" />
  <input type hidden="something here" />
</div>
```

And your form2 is in div2

```
<div id="div2" class="formDiv">
  <input type="text" id="form2" value="something" />
  <input type hidden="something here" />
</div>
```

In your CSS hide both the div (using class -- as example)

```
.formDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

Say your drop-down looks like this

```
<select id="selectForm">
<option value="div1">Form 1</option>
<option value="div2">Form 2</option>
</select>
```

Now when the user select from the drop-down list at that point change the visibility of the divs

```
$('#selectForm').on('change',function(){
   $('.formDiv').hide();
   var formID = $('#selectForm').val();  
   $(formID).css('display', 'block');
});
```

This is just an example, you can give your own IDs and CLASSes as per the feasibility and efficiency.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to keep it with two separated forms. And leave them visible! So then with javascript you can hide both forms and show the relevant one. This way if the browser does not support javascript the forms will still be usable:

```
  <select id="toggle-forms">
    <option value="1">Form 1</option>
    <option value="2">Form 2</option>
  </select>
  <form id="form-1" class="form-to-toggle" acvtion="" method="">
    <input type="text" value="something" />
    <input type hidden="something here" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit form 1"/>
  </form>
  <form id="form-2" class="form-to-toggle" acvtion="" method="">
    <input type="text" value="something" />
    <input type hidden="something here" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit form 2"/>
  </form>
  <script>
  $('#toggle-forms').on('change', function() {
    $('.form-to-toggle').hide();
    $('#form-'+this.value).show();
  }).change();
  </script>
```

See it in action: http://jsbin.com/iwocid/1

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? When  you chose option form 2 you will add testing to the input in form 2

```
<select>
<option value="1">Form 1</option>
<option value="2">Form 2</option>
</select>


//Form 1 content
<input type="text" id="form1" value="something" />
<input type hidden="something here" />

$('select').on('change',function(){
     $('input#form'+this.value).val('testing');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to form. THen use `document.getElementById('idname').innerHTML` to fill value

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this(as discussed with u)

```
<select id='this'>
<option value="Form_1">Form 1</option>
<option value="Form_2">Form 2</option>
</select>
<form id='Form_1' style='display:none'>
form1 content
</form>
<form id='Form_2' style='display:none'>
 form2 content
</form>
```

and js

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
 $('#this').change(function () {
    var form = $('#this').val();
    $('#'+form).show();
  });   
});
```